# Why am I getting an error (Invalid Scopes: openid) when trying to login to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, openid

I'm developing a game using Unity and Facebook SDK. At the moment I'm testing Facebook features so I better understand them when I add the Facebook SDK to my app. I downloaded Facebook examples from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted. When I try to log in, I get the following Error:

> Invalid Scopes: openid. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

My Facebook use cases (on my app dashboard) are:

1. Get gaming login and request data from players
2. Gaming login and requesting user data
3. Help players find friends so they can play together

What can I do to get rid of this error?
Thank you for any help!

I tried searching for similar errors and it looks like they are very common and usually resolved by adding another Use Case in the app dashboard. However, as far as I can tell, openid is not there as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by logging in as another user. I guess that's what the error message was saying - the message is only shown to me, as the developer of the app. I logged out of my account and was presented with the login screen I wanted to see. I gave the other user developer privileges and a testing role in the app dashboard and am now able to log into Facebook as this user with no errors.